# How to specify a custom last bar for Pine Script indicator?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to find a way to tell the indicator that the last bar is at for example this date `2024-01-01 16:00:00` and plots the indicator. In other words I want to set the end time for indicator. And ignore data beyond that date for calculations.

Right now the current bar is always the last bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `timestamp` to define your end time and do all your calculations and plots when `time < end time`.

Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

end_time = timestamp("Jan 01 2024 16:00:00")
can_plot = time < end_time
val = can_plot ? close : na

plot(val, color=color.white, linewidth=3)
```

[image]

If you want to keep the last value of your calculation, use a `var` variable.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to restrict the historical data range that the indicator uses for calculations? Your solution is some kind of conditional, right? I am new to Pine Script BTW :)

Comment: You can define a start time similarly. Does that help?

Comment: My original script is not that simple. I don't where to put that conditional. This is the only way?

Comment: It depends on what your end goal is. You could also create an array and place your values there conditionally.

Comment: @x_Amir_x you cannot control the original data source of the chart (if that's what you asking). You can only limit your script on which candles it will execute on.